# How to extend JTextField to generate a defined response to focusgain

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield

I suspect this is a pretty trivial question.
I wish to create a component MyTextField which extends JTextField;
The component should respond to gaining focus by changing color and respond to losing focus by changing to one of two colors depending on whether entry is valid.
How to do?

Comment: Extend your class and add focus listener to it...[How to write a focus listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your `MyTextField` class extend `JTextField` and implement `FocusListener`

**Option# 1**

```
public class MyTextField extends JTextField implements FocusListener  {
    public MyTextField (){
        addFocusListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent event) {

    }
}
```

**Option# 2**

```
public class MyTextField extends JTextField {
public MyTextField (){
    addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: Nice concept, but you may wish to use an inner class for the focus listener to prevent exposing the `focusGained/Lost` methods, as they don't need to be called by anybody else - Just a thought.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Good thinking ! I am sure above code can be easily modified to provide inner class to the `addFocusListener` function.